# Update field if date is older than

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a simple audit table:

```
schema "table" do
  field :unique_field, :string

  field :from_date, :naive_datetime
  field :to_date, :naive_datetime

  timestamps()
end
```

The `unique_field` has unique index constraint.

When a new entry is inserted, on conflict, if the `from_date` of the new entry is older than the current then I want to update the date, otherwise keep the old one.

This has to work when a lot of entries are added in parallel, meaning that an combination of `Repo.insert` and `:on_conflict` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with an `Ecto.Query` as the `on_conflict` value. More about that is described [in the Ecto documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/3.1.7/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert/2-upserts).

Didn't test it, but something like this should work:

```
unique_value = 123 # Just as an example
new_from_date = ~D[2020-06-16] # Just as an example
update_query = 
  from(t in "table",
    where: t.unique_field == ^unique_value,
    where: t.from_date < ^new_from_date,
    update: [set: [from_date: ^new_from_date]]
  )

Repo.insert(..., on_conflict: update_query, conflict_target: :unique_field)
```